# How to get badges for a user with Stacky?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I'm using the Stacky API version 1.1. Such an awesome API but I'm not sure how to get a users badges. There is a method `GetTagsByUser` but not associated `GetBadgesByUser`. Is there something I'm missing or is it just not a part of the API yet?

Comment: The API provides a method [`/user/badges`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-badges), so it is possible.  I'm not sure if Stacky implemented it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is **GetUserBadges**.

```
IEnumerable<Badge> GetUserBadges(int userId)
```

I guess it could be called GetBadgesByUser or something else. I am definitely always open to feedback about the library. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks lfoust. I see a few other bug fixes have been pushed this week. Thanks also for that :).